# LLDB Local Debugging works, but not Remote Debugging with Direct3D 11

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, lldb, direct3d

I'm attempting to remotely debug a D3D11 application. I have a Windows machine building the program with clang. The Windows machine is connected to another Windows computer that I want to debug with LLDB. When I debug locally on the target machine with LLDB, it works as expected. But when debugging from the remote machine, calling `D3D11CreateDevice` results in `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED`. The remote debugging seems to work as expected other than this, maybe there is some LLDB setting that I am unaware of?

This is what I am doing:

```
platform select remote-windows
platform connect connect://X.X.X.X:YYYY
file Target.exe
run
```

Comment: I would guess there would have to be a desktop session running for Direct3D stuff to initialize. Is Target.exe actually running in a desktop session (i.e. it would pop up on the desktop).  Maybe have the product code fallback to using software emulate driver with D3DCreate?  But if you're trying to debug actual D3D rendering, trying to do it remotely is going to be error prone. Have you tried just using Windows Remote Desktop?

Comment: @selbie The code is running on the target (debugee) machine which is a normal windows machine with a graphics card and drivers, desktop, etc, installed. The program runs on it without the debugger, and with the debugger running locally on that machine. It only does not work when I remotely debug the program. It runs on the debugger (VM) machine too, though I only found that by accident. The target machine has a 4070 ti, which I can see when I create a IDXGIFactory and loop through the adapters with EnumAdapters. Calling D3D11CreateDevice with the 4070 ti adapter (or NULL, auto) fails though.

Comment: I don't know anything about the lldb remote debugger, but are you sure it runs target.exe on the same **desktop session** as the local user logged in and not as some background service that launches processes under a debugger. That is, if you literally have both machines side by side, and you opted to debug notepad.exe, would notepad launch on the target machine.

Comment: Put it another way.  Is anyone actually logged into the target machine while you are attempting to debug from the other machine?